# Serve a seaside page/component without creating a session

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

We have a Seaside Application in place that creates a session and handles user login etc. So we're happy with that.

But we'd like to have the ability to serve a few pages using a fixed url. This is not a problem using #initialRequest: and delegating to a certain component depending on the url. What I'd like to avoid, however, is that some of these pages create a new session and start up all the machinery that's coming with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

#### Seaside 2

You could create a `WASession` (or `WAMain`) subclass which will be used if the request was static. Then in that session (or main) you could override those methods that do too much for your liking.

#### Seaside 3

You could use the new [filter mechanism](http://www.seaside.st/community/development/seaside30/WARequestHandler). If I recall correctly you can take control of the request pretty much at any time. That should give you enough leverage to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't need session state, just subclass WARequestHandler and register an instance somewhere in your handler tree (presumably in a WADispatcher).

There's some messiness currently if you want to use a Canvas for rendering but there should be some examples in the image.